# Efficient data access from docker cluster to centralized NAS

Tags: docker, networking, download, rsync, nfs

How to download efficiently large amounts of data from TrueNAS server into docker container.

Our current setup is as following: a TrueNAS Scale server is hosting the large dataset with lots of videos and corresponding calculation data (called "dataset"). Running on this TrueNAS server is an UbuntuVM which is mounting an NFS share of this ZFS pool and has a SFTP Server.

Our production docker cluster is not accessing the SFTP via PySFTP to download a dataset, do its processing and upload the results except the video back to the SFTP, deleting all the rest and downloading the next dataset for the next processing. Ideally I would only update all changed files inside the "dataset" folder structure.

The actual problem is the download speed. PySFTP has a huge speed problem so in our gigabit ethernet network we could only reach app. 20 Mbit were 700-800 Mbit were absolutely possible in case the cluster node is pulling a new docker image on our own DockerHub hosted on the exact same VM. So the problem is the SFTP and not the network itself.

Now is the question how we should rearrange this setup to overcome this bottleneck? My ideas reach from:

1. Mount the NFS share directly into each docker.
2. Use some rsync, cp, mv via SSH directly to the TrueNAS Scale
3. Implement some "other" server on the VM to manage the requests from the dockers more efficient.

I'm wondering if the risk of data corruption gets higher if I grab directly from each docker via an NFS share into the main data bucket? Potentially two dockers could upload the same files at the same moment or they were shut down during upload, leading to corrupted datasets.

In the past we uploaded the dataset into a "_temp" folder and only if the code reached the very end of the upload, SFTP was told to delete the original one and rename the "_temp". But I'm wondering if there was never invented something far more intelligent that this attempt? Also with an eye on performance.